# Move Marker along route in mapbox android

Tags: android, routes, mapbox, marker

I need to move the marker from source location to destination along route.

How can I do this in mapbox.

Please help me out from this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use onLocation change to get cuurent location, and make sure you are getting it .and then put this code to again reset marker on the new location

```
googleMap.clear();
mLAt=location.getLatitude();
mLong=location.getLongitude();
onlochangelatlnglatLng=new LatLng(mLAt,mLong);

googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(onlochangelatlnglatLng).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.loccar)).title("My location"));
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location changed! +LAt"+mLAt+ "mlongggg"+mLong,
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it is not related to googleMap. But my code is related to mapbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can update your markers either by bookkeeping your marker configuration like so:

```
List<MarkerViewOptions> optionsList = new ArrayList<>();
optionsList.add(new MarkerViewOptions()
    .title("My title")
    .snippet("My snippet")
    .position(new LatLng(0, 0))
    .icon(someIcon));
```

Then you can choose to update information from the `optionsList` using getters and setters. Me personally, I like getting the marker from the `MapboxMap` variable inside the `onMapReady` method inside the `OnMapReadyCallback` interface. You can do this like so:

```
mapboxMap.getMarkers().get(indexOfMarkerYouWantToChange)
    .setPosition(new LatLng(newLat, newLng));
```

Comment: How do you get the value for indexOfMarkerYouWantToChange ?

Comment: @ssimm depending on what order the markers were added (I'm assuming there is more than one marker), I just hardcode the index of the marker with a value ranging from 0 to total markers - 1. For example, if you had 3 markers where the first was the starting point, second the current location, and third the destination point and you wanted to update the current location, do `mapboxMap.getMarkers().get(1)`